# Error 1064 when updating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

When updating a table I get an error:

My table is 
speech

values:

```
no  speec   check
1   45      0
```

and the structure is :

```
1 -no   int(100)            No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext

2- speec    varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext

3 - check   int(100)            No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
```

when updating using the command :

```
UPDATE speech set check=1 where no=1
```

I get the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'check=1 where no=1' at line 1

Please help me in this issue

Comment: Why tag SQL Server when it's MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

`CHECK` is a reserved, word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

You need to escape it using backtics as

```
UPDATE speech set `check`=1 where no=1
```